# Badges in notification system cannot be read

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I finally got the Taxonomist badge (yay!) and noticed that you can't read the tag text in the notification bar which appears at the top of the screen.

[image: Taxonomist notification]

Comment: Congratulations, by the way. Also, nice catch.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that -- links in notifications are supposed to be unadorned. Will fix!